# Prove that $||A||_2 = \sqrt{\max|\lambda_i(A^TA)|}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, numerical-methods

I need to prove that

$$||A||_2 = \sqrt{\max|\lambda_i(A^T A)|}$$

Any ideas how to start?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044929/l2-norm-of-a-matrix-is-this-statement-true

Comment: See Corollary 4.2 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/matrixnorm.pdf (so you'll need earlier results like Theorem 4.1).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).